# change background Image of buttons in outletCollection

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have OutletCollection of buttons

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *someBtn;
```

I need to change the  backgroundImage of buttons which are pressed.

I try to make this for each

```
for (UIButton *btn in _someBtn) {
if (btn.tag == 1) {
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage ....................:forControl....]
} else if (btn.tag == 2) {
[btn setBackgroundImage:UIImage ......................]
}
```

But when i press on a button with the tag "1", image changes on the button with 1 and 2 and so on.
Thanks for answers...

Comment: [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"quantity_box.png"]
                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through all buttons and changing the image on each with a tag matching your if statements, you need to check that the button is the selected one, e.g.

```
for (UIButton *button in _someBtn)
{
    if (button == selectedButton)
    {
        [button setBackgroundImage:someImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

or if you want to use tags

```
UIButton *button = [buttonSuperview viewWithTag:whicheverTag];
[button setBackgroundImage:someImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: First  variant buttons doesnt get a bGImage... Two variant is warning from view to button...

Answer (score 0):

Resolved...

```
for (UIButton *btn in _someBtn) {
NSLog(@"pressed button is:%ld", (long)btn.tag)
if ([btn isTouchInside]) {
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
}
```